# Convert a decimal number to HH:MM:SS in R

Tags: r, chron

I have a series of decimal numbers (marathon race split times): 64.90, etc., and I want to convert it into HH:MM:SS format using R so that I can us the result to do time math. The answer I am looking for is: 1:04:54.

chron doesn't seem to be doing what I'm expecting it to do.

> chron::times(64.90)
>   Time in days:
>   [1] 64.9

First time on this site, so be kind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

chron times are measured in days and since you apparently have minutes divide the input by the number of minutes in a day:

```
library(chron)

times(64.90 / (24 * 60))
## [1] 01:04:54
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `lubridate::seconds_to_period`

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(64.90)
[1] "1M 4.90000000000001S"
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove seconds digits (without regex)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
library(hms)
as.hms(64.90*60)
```

output

```
01:04:54
```