# getting wrong output when changing hours(not formatted)into hh:mm in R

Tags: r, time, chron

I have a column within a data frame containing hours that was created by dividing by 60 from another column that is comprised of minutes and would like them formatted to hh:mm

I found this post to be helpful:
[Convert a decimal number to HH:MM:SS in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088387/convert-a-decimal-number-to-hhmmss-in-r)

but the output is not correct for example

```
   Duration.h.mm
1   1.93
2   0.62
3   2.24
```

```
library(chron)

times(rd$Duration.h.mm / (24 *60))

## output :
   Duration.h.mm
1   00:01:56
2   00:00:37
3   00:02:14
```

I'm after

1   1:56
2   0:37
3   2:14

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
> format(strptime(times(rd$Duration.h.mm / (24*60)),"%H:%M:%S"),'%M:%S')
[1] "01:56" "00:37" "02:14"
```